# Jenkins parameters with axis

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a pipeline with parameters.

```
parameters {
  choice(name: 'platform',choices:['windows','linux','solaris'])
}
```

I would like to have an axis with values of each choices. like

```
axes {
  axis {
    name 'platform_axis'
    values ${param.platform}
  }
}
```

Does Jenkins support something like that?

Comment: If it's a choice before, what is the purpose of the axis ?

Comment: If I select a choice, then do only that choice. Otherwise, do all the choices.